# Why does the size of the t-log backup we get in the bulk_logged recovery model decrease in some cases?

Tags: sql-server

The bulk_logged recovery model should also increase the size of the t-log file when we take a t-log backup.Because in this case, both log records and data pages are inside the t-log backup.
I checked this on some tests:

1. I created a database and set full recovery model
2. I created a table and inserted above 2gb data
3. Taked t-log backup
4. Inserted above 2gb data
5. Taked t-log backup
6. Set bulk_logged recovery model
7. Inserted data and taked t-log backup

Then I compared the sizes of t-log backups

[image]

Why didn't the size of the t-log backup we got in the bulk_logged recovery model increase?

Comment: Read the [documentaton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). Quote: Reduces log space usage by using minimal logging for most bulk operations. You should choose a recovery model that matches your needs - size of backups should not be a primary concern.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you backup the transaction log, the transactions stored inside the file are purged out. So the different backup do not cumulate old backuped transactions...
When using the bulk logged model for recovery, some SQL transactions are not entierly write into the transaction log. It is why the size of the last backup is lightly smaller.